# TextAreaFor and EditorFor borders are different shades

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I make the borders of TextAreaFor and EditorFor look the same. One is darker then the other.

[image]

```
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.New, 4, 50, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "form-control",@style="border:0.2rem" })
```

The compiler can eat some parameters to edit.
Your experiment will solve this way.